# Значение JSpinner: можно ли запретить пользователю вводить что-либо кроме чисел?

Tags: java

Значение JSpinner: можно ли запретить пользователю вводить что-либо кроме чисел и как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

При чтении значения JSpinner сделайте попытку вызвать конструктор числа, при генерации исключения очищайте значение JSpinner.
Так же можете подписаться на событие потеря фокуса и там делать проверку на то, является значение числом или нет, и так же очищайте JSpinner.